# Data constructor not in scope despite copy-pasting exact code and importing module

Tags: haskell, module, stateful, state-monad

I'm trying to run one of the most simple examples from the Haskell online book where you implement a stateful function modeling a stack of numbers. The code from the example I'm using is (http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state):

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Stack = [Int]  

pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  
  
push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)
```

Yet when trying to load it in Prelude I get:

```
state.hs:6:7: error:
    Data constructor not in scope:
      State :: ([a0] -> (a0, [a0])) -> State Stack Int
  |
6 | pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  
  |       ^^^^^

state.hs:9:10: error:
    Data constructor not in scope:
      State :: ([Int] -> ((), [Int])) -> State Stack ()
  |
9 | push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)  
  |          ^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

What am I missing??? Is this example somehow wrong?

I was just expecting to simply load the module with no errors. No clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, the [`Control.Monad.State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-State.html) module does not contain a data constructor called `State`. That would be the case if it simply defined

```
newtype State' s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

– which it used to do [in version 1 of the `mtl` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html), but doesn't anymore. Since version 2.0, the module only exports a *type synonym* called `State`, which is actually re-exported from [`Control.Monad.Trans.State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.6/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html) and is implemented thus:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

The [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) monad makes this behave so that `m (a,s)` is isomorphic to simply `(a,s)` by itself, so in the end `StateT s Identity a` is indeed isomorphic to `State' s a`. It is however more general: `StateT` is a *monad transformer* that can also be stacked on top of other monadic actions, such as `IO`.

So you can't use a `State` value constructor, but you can use [`state`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.6/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:state) which behaves exactly as `State` behaved in `mtl-1.1`. (Except you can't pattern match on it, but you can still use [`runState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.6/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:runState).)

```
pop :: State Stack Int
pop = state $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)
  
push :: Int -> State Stack ()
push a = state $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That did the trick. The code is wrong in the example, then!

Comment: Yes, this is because LYAH is quite old. I added some explanation on the history of this discrepancy.

Comment: In hindsight, and with more modern tools, the library could have exported a pattern synonym to somewhat preserve backward compatibility.